# Code transformation

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn

Is there a concept of code transformation in c# just like it is in dart?

Example of why i want that:

- if i annotate a property i want to change the implementation of the
  setter.
- i want to generate json,xml serialization methods per class to avoid reflection and
  add them as extension methods
- generating methods that allows me to get/set a property by
  name without using reflection.

and much more.

i wrote a Roslyn project to make me able to do the above and its working great but the problem is i don't want to see the generated code in my solution but rather want it to be generated every time i compile.

any ideas?

Comment: Search for "aspect oriented programming", also look at "Fody" and "PostSharp"

Comment: T4 templates can also achieve some of your points.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel i know except for the code modification parts

Comment: @user1492051 combining T4 with AOP might do the trick then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in support for making this work nicely; it's something we're currently thinking about though.